# Как сделать что клиент мог отрабатывать команды от сервера

Tags: python, клиент-сервер

Есть сервер 
server:

```
import socket                                         


serversocket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 


host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999                                           


serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  


serversocket.listen(5)                                           

while True:

    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

    msg='Thank you for connecting'+ "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

И есть клиент:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999
s.connect((host, port))                               
msg = s.recv(1024)                                     

s.close()

print (msg.decode('ascii'))
```

Мне нужно чтобы я отправлял с server команды типа:tree,dir,cd на клиент и чтобы итог выводился  на сервере 
Например:
На стационаре где установлен client есть text.txt,photo.png 
Я с сервера ввожу dir команда выполняется на клиенте но чтобы итог возвратился  на сервер 
Надеюсь я понятно объяснил

Comment: ну собственно в коде клиента пишите обработку входящего от сервера сообщения, выполняете действие и отправляете результат на сервер ... А готовый код вряд ли кто то за вас напишет

Comment: Вы хотите одному клиенту команду послать или всем подключённым (broadcast)? По сути любая реализация чата (простой вариант) или  MMORPG (сложный) подойдёт (вместо работы напрямую с сокетами, попробуйте библиотеки более высокого уровня к примеру , используемые для irc, telegram ботов. Когда клиенты это обычные веб-браузеры (JavaScript), может подойти Flask-SocketIO. В более общем случае (надёжность, масштабируемость) [OTP архитектура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Telecom_Platform) может быть полезна для подобных задач.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найди в гугле книгу Violent python и начинай читать вторую главу с 54 страницы. Там все уже готово, осталось только скопировать.

```
import optparse
import pxssh

class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.session = self.connect()

     def connect(self):
         try:
             s = pxssh.pxssh()
             s.login(self.host, self.user, self.password)
             return s
         except Exception, e:
             print e
             print '[-] Error Connecting'

     def send_command(self, cmd):
         self.session.sendline(cmd)
         self.session.prompt()
         return self.session.before

     def botnetCommand(command):
         for client in botNet:
            output = client.send_command(command)
            print '[*] Output from ' + client.host
            print '[+] ' + output + '\n'

     def addClient(host, user, password):
         client = Client(host, user, password)
         botNet.append(client)

botNet = []

# примеры:
addClient('10.10.10.110', 'root', 'toor')
addClient('10.10.10.120', 'root', 'toor')
addClient('10.10.10.130', 'root', 'toor')
botnetCommand('uname -v')
botnetCommand('cat /etc/issue')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: В коде ошибка, в функции `addClient`, сразу после добавления новго клиента в `botNet`, происходит обнуление списка. Скорее всего отсутпы лишние.

Comment: Можешь добавить правку